# How can I restrict alphabet in input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I'm using input text field to input numbers only. I can't use input type="number" because i probably use the decimal or (.) characters

Example of expected result:

1. whole numbers
2. numbers with decimal
3. restricted alphabets

If possible, only decimal character are allowed, the rest will restricted also in special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

In the attribute step , you can define your steps like **.01**.

```
<input type="number" required name="price" min="0" value="0" step="any">
```

**jQuery**

In case you are looking for a regex that allows only numbers with an optional 2 decimal places

HTML:

```
<input name="my_field" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" />
```

JS / jQuery:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input[pattern]', function(e){
  var input = $(this);
  var oldVal = input.val();
  var regex = new RegExp(input.attr('pattern'), 'g');

  setTimeout(function(){
    var newVal = input.val();
    if(!regex.test(newVal)){
      input.val(oldVal); 
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Regex check for input, allow only numeric value and decimal. And if condition check, it's only take one decimal.

Example:

```js
$(".decimal").on("input", function(evt) {
  var txt = $(this).val();
  txt = txt.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
  if (txt.split('.').length > 2)
    txt = txt.replace(/\.+$/, "");
  $(this).val(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="numeric" class='decimal'>
```

Comment: What is Jquery used for in this example?

Comment: @EliRichardson Because question tag with jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

using jquery validation is easily possible for input

```html
Enter Input try it. <br/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57" onpaste="return false">
```